# How to match a keyword against a value and then assign the value accordingly to a variable in Splunk?

Tags: pattern-matching, conditional-statements, splunk, multiple-monitors

I have a case where I need to monitor primary and backup sensors simultaneously. But before that I need to figure out the primary and backup sensors.

I've something like this :

```
**sensor**

sensor1

sensor1_backup

sensor2

sensor2_backup

sensor3

sensor3_backup
```

I want to check against the sensor to see if its a backup sensor and then need to know whose backup it is.

I tried something like this :

```
... | eval backup_sensor=if(match(sensor,*backup*,1,0),sensor)
```

But, if match is true I can assign the sensor to backup. But how to assign the sensor to a new field "primary_sensor" if it fails.

Also, how can I do to identify whose backup it is.

For ex, I find one backup sensor "sensor2_backup", should I again need to use match statement to see if its a backup for sensor2 ?

Answer (score 0):

The `match` function will work, but like you mentioned, you'll likely need two of them.  Also, `match` uses regular expressions rather than patterns.

A better approach is `rex`.  It also uses regular expressions, but can easily extract multiple fields.  Try this:

```
... | rex field=sensor "(?<primary_sensor>[^_]+)_(?<backup_sensor>backup>.*)"
```